# How can I test a bench DC power supply?

Tags: power, dc, testing

I am about to receive a new dual 30V/5A DC bench power supply.
The goal is to use it in lieu of batteries to build simple circuits.

I'd like to test it out when I get it, but don't really know how to do that.

I need to know if it does what it's supposed to while it can still be returned if faulty.

How can I "put it through its paces?"

- Do I use resistors in series (with a potentiometer) to build a circuit?
- Do I need to go beyond a breadboard, given its power capabilities?

Comment: do you have a multimeter? Using that and a "weak" resistor (anything upwards of 470 Ω, probably) you could simply test whether it supplies the set voltages. And if it has current limiting, your multimeter in current test mode shorting your supply will be a good test of the accuracy of the current limiting (just be **really** sure to know how to limit the current before you do that).

Comment: Other than that – it's a bench power supply. The whole point of having it is that it "just works"; I wouldn't put too much time into testing it after an initial voltage test (you're probably not in a situation where you could test the dynamic properties that might not be stated on the data sheet, anyways). Build something that you *wanted* to build, anyways, even if it's just an LED with a series resistor that lights up :)

Comment: I would do a low-load/no-load voltage check as well as a startup voltage check (i.e. turn it on and see that the voltage rises to the set value without significant overshoot).

Comment: Since it's a dual supply, don't forget to verify that both sides output the same voltage when the dials are set to the same value. It's extremely annoying when a matched pair get calibrated *just slightly* off from each other.

Comment: You seem to be asking about electrical checks, but do turn it upside down and give it a little shake to make sure there are no loose parts inside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually there are check-out instructions in the operating and service manuals. If you use a web search engine query of the manufacturer and model number plus “service manual”, often these documents can be downloaded at no cost.

Comment: great idea -- thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Truck headlamps are 24 V. A 55 W bulb will draw about 55 / 24 = > 2 A. Parallel two of them and you can test up to about 26 - 28 V (but they'll be close to popping). Put three in parallel to test the current limit function.

Test the two supplies individually and then together depending on how many lamps you have.

Bear in mind that the bulbs will have very low resistance when cold so you may see a surge in current if you switch on full voltage rather than ramp them up. This should show up as a brief over-current indication on the PSU.

Comment: European trucks are 24 V. Designs from the rest of the world currently use 12 V. Some older US 24 V trucks only used that for starting, the rest of the system ran on 12. Thus, 24 V bulbs are harder to find outside Europe.

Comment: In addition, run this near-max output test for a period of time to ensure that the unit doesn't overheat.  Some shady companies will post specs that their units can output but only by over-driving them for short periods of time. Your unit should be able to maintain the listed output for an extended period without overheating or becoming dangerously hot to the touch.

Comment: @user71659 2 12V bulbs in series will work as well. A H4 bulb with the two filaments in series is also good for a minute or two.

Comment: @Transistor 28V (or even 29-30V when very cold and the regulator is thermally compensated) are the normal alternator voltages, so the 24V truck bulbs will be not be close to popping, but at or near their intended operating mode instead.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the functional tests in the other answers, I would suggest a few basic safety tests, before plugging it in.

Using a multimeter on its continuity range, check that there is no continuity between the live/hot pin on the plug and the case of the power supply.  If it has a grounding point, use that.  Otherwise an exposed case screw will do.
Also check no continuity between neutral and the case.

Check that the ground/earth pin of the plug *is* connected to the case.

Don't assume that it was connected right in the factory.  I have a bench power supply I bought second-hand.  It failed the grounding test.  On opening it up, the manufacturer had forgotten to connect the ground wire to the solder tag that had been screwed into the case.

Answer (score 0):

Use a lightbulb or get a large resistor, even a pipe or a piece of metal will work if you take care to insulate it, both thermally and electrically. Make sure if you do use a low resistance conductor you also have good cabling (like better than 22AWG cable, the bigger the better). Also one thing you might also want to check is the AC ripple (noise) when you do put it through it's paces. The Chinese switcher supplies can have quite a lot of noise on them (like 10's of mV of ripple). A good bench supply will have in the low mV range.

Comment: I'm guessing the whole ripple thing would require an oscilloscope (don't have one yet)

Comment: You can get a good idea with a multi meter with an AC or ACrms mode

Comment: could I get you to expand a bit on that process?

Comment: Yeah, you put the multimeter across the terminals of the power supply in voltage AC mode (probably mV if the Dmm has one)

Comment: @DrSmokeWrench This is unrelated to your question, but some advice from a former hobbyist: a half-decent oscilloscope (either a used one off ebay, or a new one from Rigol or Siglent's budget lines) should probably be the next thing you buy after having a multimeter and a bench power supply. I went too long without having one in my hobbyist days, simply because they were far too expensive--it's great you can get them so cheaply now.

Comment: @Hearth - I have already come to the same conclusion and appreciate the confirmation

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a typical laboratory DC power supply, you could do the following tests with multimeter:

1. With power disconnected, measure in resistance range that there is no connection between output terminals and any of the pins on the mains plug. There are some power supplies where the output is connected to mains earth, but if that is the case you want to know it. Some power supplies have a separate earth terminal (usually green), which of course should show connection to mains earth.
2. Connect power and measure in DC voltage range that the output voltages are correct. Test at least the maximum and minimum output voltages.
3. With multimeter in AC voltage range, check that it shows close to 0 V. This is a crude indication that the output voltage is stable, but it could still fluctuate under load and at higher frequencies than your multimeter can measure.
4. With multimeter in 10A current range, check that the current limiting functionality of the power supply works. If you set the power supply to 1 A output, a multimeter in current mode across the terminals should get that current. This has the potential to blow the fuse in your multimeter if the current limiting does not work, which can be avoided by starting at 0 volts setting and slowly raising it.

Answer (score 0):

There are instruments available for this sort of testing, and I thought I would mention it, although I understand if you don't want to spend that kind of money (about $500 and up).

The equipment you want here is called a "dynamic load".  This allows you to apply a precise load of your choosing to the supply.  With the right one, you can push all the corners of the envelope of that bench supply.

Here is an inexpensive one I am familiar with:  Rigol DL3000  a 200W unit would work for your application.

I use these to test the embedded power supplies in systems.  Voltage and current limits, transient response, that sort of thing.

Other than that, I would just use your bench supply maybe with a 1K resistor, and check the voltage and current using a multimeter just to get a sense for how accurate the built-in gauges are (assuming it has gauges).

Comment: thanks for your response -- it's not really helpful to me due to the reason that my original question was edited -- in the process the FACT that I am an absolute beginner was removed

Comment: No need for resistors when using it to power a circuit.  You should be able to adjust the voltage and current limit on the bench supply.   The current limit feature allows you to set the MAXIMUM current the bench supply will deliver.  This can be useful when you first power on a circuit, if you are not sure about it.  What model is your bench power supply?

Comment: If you don't have a multimeter, you should get one.  This is the first tool for working with electronics.  They are relatively cheap and also accurate.  I recommend a Fluke - they have many models at various price points - like $40 and up.

Comment: thanks for that -- I do indeed have DMMs.